# Time values get copy-pasted as decimals

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where column L has some time entries. Like 09:00, 12:00, 15:00 etc. (I'm from Europe, so it's 24h and not am/pm). The format is custom, hh:mm.

I tried to get entries like "12:00 o'clock" in the target cell:

```
ws.Cells(30, columnTimeline).Value = wsFiltered.Range("L" & foundRowFiltered).Value & " o'clock"
```

The code is fine, `columnTimeline` and `foundRowFiltered` are valid references that point to the right cell. However, I get "0.5 o'clock". I tried copy pasting the original data as values, but I end up with the same format (0.5 instead of 12:00).

Here are some examples of what the times get converted to:

```
12:00 -> 0.5
13:00 -> 0.54167
14:00 -> 0.583
15:00 -> 0.625
16:00 -> 0.67
19:00 -> 0.79167
22:00 -> 0.9167
```

Comment: use `Format$` to format the time value before appending your string to it. Alternatively, use the `.Text` property instead of the `.Value` property since it is already formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Times are float values in Excel.
You need to use format to format the float value to "time".

```
ws.Cells(30, columnTimeline).Value = format(wsFiltered.Range("L" & foundRowFiltered).Value, "hh:mm") & " o'clock"
```

The integer of the value is the date, counting from 1900-01-01.
Meaning 1.5 in Excel means 1900-01-02 12:00.

Edit:
I believe a better way to do it is to not add "o'clock" to the cell.
Just add the time and then use costum format of the cell and add "o'clock".
That way you can copy or use the time in math without using string operations.